# Why AutoCompleteTextView has such a weird name?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, autocompletetextview

I've got a simple but stupid question.

Why **`AutoCompleteTextView`** has **TextView** in it's name, while it has all properties of **EditText**?

Or is there any kind of properties of **TextView**? Correct me please if i am not right.

Answer (score 1):

It is a strange question indeed. But answering - AutoCompleteTextView extends EditText and EditText extends TextView.

Hope that's satisfying answer.

Comment: Thank's for answering! That's really weird. Why just don't call it **`AutoCompleteEditText`**, or **`SpinnableEditText`**, it would have much better. However, thank's for an answer.

Comment: Or you can post it as a bug:
https://source.android.com/setup/report-bugs